# How to fix mysql stack overrun error

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I get the following error when trying to insert into a record:

```
Thread stack overrun:  5768 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

I am using Mac OSX - Lion. will someone please show me how to fix this problem: maybe with the line of command to run in the terminal. thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE `string_data` (
 `stringId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `languageCode` char(4) NOT NULL,
 `stringData` text,
 `modifiedDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`stringId`,`languageCode`),
 KEY `languageCode` (`languageCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Inserting a record shouldn't overflow the stack... do you have some "heavy" triggers attached to that table?

Comment: I don't think so. I am adding the table schema in the original post.

Comment: Looks like it's come up a few times before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919558/mysql-servers-thread-stack-parameter-what-is-it-how-big-should-it-be - The fix is to set the thread_stack variable to 256k.  It's impossible to tell why your query causes this error.

Comment: I read that thread. it does not show how to set the thread_stack to 256K; it just says to do it. Does anyone know how?

Comment: It's a command line parameter, so I guess it depends how you're starting mySql.

Answer (score 3):

I have just come across this when trying to create and run a simple stored proc (using mysql on OSX also) 
 
I put:

```
[mysqld]
thread_stack=256k
```

in `~/.my.cnf` file and then restarted the mysql server to fix it.