# Case insensitive custom replace() function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, replace, user-defined-functions

I'm attempting to do a batch replace on a database to *translate* british to american words. I've got a large array of words to replace, and also an array of various different tables to run through. I've come across the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656056/case-insensitive-replace-in-mysql) that appears to provide exactly what I need, however I'm getting errors when trying it.

This is the error I'm encountering.

```
Exception caught: exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1436 Thread stack overrun:
10816 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.
Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.' in /var/.../....php:303
Stack trace: #0 /var/.../....php(303): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main}
```

I'm using the custom defined MySQL function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244279/871150) and generating a query that looks like this;

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value = case_insensitive_replace(body_value, :british, :american)
```

I'm using the following to handle the PDO;

```
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
try {
    $query->execute($sql_fields_array);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exception caught: $e";
}
```

The `$sql_fields_array` array looks like this;

```
Array ( [british] => acclimatise [american] => acclimate )
```

I've tested changing the name of the custom function to make sure I created it correctly, and I did get an error saying the function name did not exist. So at least that part of what I've tried is correct.

Originally I was using the `replace(lower(body_value), :british, :american)` to do the search and replace, however this then changed everything to lowercase which is not what I want.

Any ideas with this error? Or if there's actually a better way I can automate this batch search and replace.

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919558/mysql-servers-thread-stack-parameter-what-is-it-how-big-should-it-be which give information on the "thread_stack" stuff.

Comment: So this is a kind of *not enough memory to perform the operation* type of problem? Are there any dangers with raising the thread stack limit? Mine appears to be 128K

Comment: I'm not specialist, but except for global memory consumption in case of alot of batches running at the same moment, I think it would be fine to raise the thread_stack value.

Comment: Well at least for now it seems to be ok. I've raised it to 256K and the query ran this time! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query appears to be working fine. After raising the thread stack from 128K to 256K the query successfully executed. It took a good 20-30 seconds mind you, but ran non the less.

I've not noticed any adverse effects on the server after increasing this limit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a duplicate of [MySQL error 1436: Thread stack overrun, with simple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query).

Posting it here since don't have comment rights.

Regards